# SOS: Working LightGBM model script to find best model

Tags: classification, r, lightgbm, error-handling

I have been trying to get a working LightGBM model which I can train on my data, select the best performing model with highest f1 score and then use it obtain the f1 score on the testing data. However, all the material I have found online gives me errors.

Currently, what I am doing is after splitting the data and test set (70:30), and preparing cv folds, I prepare the recipe, then the tuning parameters etc., eventually examining the models for parameter selection using F1 scores.

I have data which I want to use to predict the loan_default status and whether someone will default or not, using 21 predictors in my data set, using downsampling.

Does anyone have a working script or helpful resources?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there are usually a lot of full solution code notebooks available in Kaggle for these sorts of problems. Here's a couple I was able to find based on a quick Google search:

- https://www.kaggle.com/code/duydnn/credit-default-predict-lightgbm-model-explain-r/notebook
- https://www.kaggle.com/code/psystat/titanic-lightgbm-modeling-with-r/report
- https://www.kaggle.com/code/andrewmvd/lightgbm-in-r/report

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).